# How can I create an EU quiz without 28 "if" statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating an EU quiz. I have gotten up to:

```
import random as r
import timeit as tr

import time as t

print "How many questions would you like?"
q = int(raw_input())

count = 0
while q > count:
        aus_country = r.randrange(1,29)
        from random import choice
        if aus_country == 28:
    country = "Austria"
        country_1 = ['Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic',           'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom']
        country = choice(country_1)
        print "What is the capital of", country
        ans = raw_input()
        """I would not like to have 28 if statements here like:
        count = count + 1
```

However, I would like to know if there is a better way of checking the capitals then having 28 if statements like:

```
if ans == London and country == United_Kindom:
    print "Correct"
if ans == Vienna and country == austria:
    print "Correct
...
else:
    print "Wrong"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store Country->Capital, and look it up using that:

```
capital = {
    'UK': 'London',
    'Austria': 'Vienna'
}

if ans == capital[country]:
    # it's correct
```

---

I would also re-work it to be based on something to pick a random number of countries (without duplicates) and use that as the main loop...

```
import random    

number = int(raw_input())
countries = random.sample(capital, number)
for country in countries:
    guess = raw_input('What is the capital of {}?'.format(country))
    if guess == capital[country]:
        print 'Correct!'
```

Answer (score 0):

store country name and capital as a dictionary of key:value pair and see if the answer value matches the key pair - the answer is correct if not answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a class for handling the dictionary, since you probably want to grow with time and be flexible on the data. On the other hand, maybe you want to learn some OOP style of coding.

```
import random

class QuizLexicon(object):
    """
    A quiz lexicon with validation and random generator.

    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def validate_answer(self, key, answer):
        """Check if the answer matches the data, ignoring case."""
        if self.data[key].lower() == answer.lower():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def random_choice(self):
        """Return one random key from the dictionary."""
        return random.choice([k for k in self.data])

sample_data = {'Hungary': 'Budapest', 'Germany': 'Berlin'}
quiz_lexicon = QuizLexicon(sample_data)

print "How many questions would you like?"
n_questions = int(raw_input())

for _ in range(n_questions):
    key = quiz_lexicon.random_choice()
    print("What is the capital of %s" % key)
    answer = raw_input()
    if quiz_lexicon.validate_answer(key, answer):
        print("That's right!")
    else:
        print("No, sorry")
```